# Error when attempting to geo-restore Azure PostgreSQL flexible server

Tags: postgresql, azure, restore, disaster-recovery, azure-regions

I am doing some testing for my dev team around disaster recover... and specifically disaster recovery for Azure PostgreSQL flexible server. I spun up a test PostgreSQL server in the WestUS2 region with a test database/schema and some test data. I then wanted to try restoring this database (simulating a regional disaster scenario) using the Geo-redundant restore option (restore to paired region (westcentralus)).

[See restore configuration details here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n743l.png)

After I configure all the respective settings and try to create the new server, I get the following error almost immediately:

[Deployment Details:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnnE.png)

And after clicking on "Operation details", this additional info:
`{ "status": "Failed", "error": { "code": "InternalServerError", "message": "An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'" } }`

Does anyone have an idea why this would occur?

I've tried other restore options (latest restore and fast restore) and both were successful. I just can't get the geo-redundant restore to work!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update anyone who reads this post... I tried the exact same steps I documented days later, and I was able to successfully perform a geo restore of my postgres database. Not sure why it worked this time... perhaps my initial request just wasn't prioritized by Azure at the time? Or an error on their side of things that is no longer present.